# Why am I getting different results from two functions in my dice roll simulator in python?

Tags: python, function, simulate

I have written two functions in a Jupyter Notebook to simulate rolling dice:

1. One set of x dice, with d faces n times.
2. Two sets of dice with different x and d values, n times.

The simulated dice rolls are then plotted in a histogram. The first function works fine, but the second function is not working as I expected. For example if I simulate rolling four, 6 sided dice, 1000 times with my first function, I get very different results to rolling 2 sets of two, 6 sided dice, 1000 times with my second function. My code is below:

function for single dice roll:

```py
def roll_dice(x, d):
    """
    Function to simulate rolling x fair dice with d number of faces
    """
    roll = 0
    for i in range(x):
        roll += np.random.randint(1, d + 1)
    return roll
```

First function to simulate rolling one set of dice n times:

```py
def simulate_dice_rolls(n, x, d):
    """This function simulates n dice rolls, for x number of dice, with d number of faces."""
    results = []
    for i in range(n):
        results.append(roll_dice(x, d))
    results = np.asarray(results)
    return results
```

Second function to simulate rolling two sets of dice:

```py
def simulate_two_sets_dice_rolls(n, x1, d1, x2, d2):
    """This simulates rolling two different sets of dice (with xi number of dice with di number of faces) n times"""
    results_2 = []
    for i in range(n):
        results_2.append(roll_dice(x1, d1))
        results_2.append(roll_dice(x2, d2))

    results_2 = np.asarray(results_2)
    return results_2
```

These are the Histograms produced:
[Histogram 1 - Single set of dice rolls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I1iY.png)
[Histogram 2 - Two sets of dice rolls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1zFG.png)

Why are these functions giving different results, when they both call the same 'roll_dice' function, and appending the results to a list?
My notebook can be viewed on Github [here](https://github.com/Richard-D-Todd/Learning/blob/master/Dice%20Rolling.ipynb)

Comment: You're calling `roll_dice` twice as many times in the second example.  There's no way the histograms could be equal.

Comment: The hint is in your max values in your histograms. What is the max possible sum of 4d6? and what is the max possible sum of 2d6?

Comment: To elaborate on @G.Anderson answer, in in the first function `x=4` so you're counting sums of four dice. In the second function, you independently append two rolls of two dice (`x1 = x2 = 2`). This leads to different scale in two histograms, where the second one is a 2x compressed version of the first.

Comment: Ah @Marat I see my mistake now. I was basically running the same simulated dice rolls twice. What I actually want to be doing in the second function is summing the results of the two calls to the roll_dice function. I've changed it so that the lists are cast to np arrays so that I can use simple vector addition to sum them element wise. Thanks for the help everyone!